# displays all data with certain field types, from the results of the query

Tags: mysql, sql

displays all data with certain field types, from the results of the query ...
I do queries in three tables, and only show data that has relations only, whereas I want to display everything even though there is no relation ...

> the data that I have

[image]

> I want to display the data as below

[image]

Comment: second image display ,, the sql display that I want is correct ... I've tried it several times ... but it failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use left join in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.position,c.nama from posisi a,kanaikan_posisi b,bana c
where a.id_position = b.id_position (+) and c.id_karyavan (+) = b.id_karyavan
order by a.id_position
```